# Rails nested attributes errors not propagated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-attributes

I have the following models:

```rb
class CourseSection < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :tasks, through: :content_refs, source: :content, source_type: "Task"
  ...
end

class ContentRef < ApplicationRecord
  before_destroy do
    if task_completions.any?
      errors.add(:content_ref, "has associated task completions and can't be deleted. Try archiving it instead.")
      course_section.errors.add(:content_ref, "has associated task completions and can't be deleted. Try archiving it instead.")
      throw(:abort)
    end
  end

  belongs_to :course_section
  has_one :task, :through => :self_ref, :source => :content, :source_type => 'Task'
  ...
end

class Task < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :referring_content_refs, as: :content, dependent: :destroy, class_name: "ContentRef"
  ...
end
```

I am operating the tasks through nested attributes in the CourseSectionsController as such:

```rb
@course_section.update update_attributes_params
```

where update_attributes_params is

```
<ActionController::Parameters {"tasks_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"title"=>"Task", "id"=>"6", "_destroy"=>"1"}}} permitted: true>
```

Based on these params, it tries to destroy the Task, which triggers the dependent: :destroy and tries to destroy the ContentRef. There the before_destroy is triggered and performs the check and (in this case) enters the if, inserts the errors and aborts. In the end this results in the Task not being destroyed as I want it to be, but the `@course_section` in the controller doesn't have any errors, so it doesn't know that something went wrong. Also the `.update` returns true, which I also don't understand. Shouldn't it know that there was an abort and return false?

Right now, in this situation, the controller acts as if there wasn't any problem and the update was successful.

Comment: Try to add `errors.add(:base, "Base error")`

Comment: Doesn't work. I believe :base means that the error is related to the whole model and not only a single of its attributes. I don't think that has anything to do with the propagation.

Comment: are you sure that `task_completions` is not empty ?

Comment: Yes, I am completely sure. I used byebug and it clearly enters the if and adds the error.